# How to find Sum of DateTime using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have a collection of class with a DateTime Property, I would like to get sum of Minutes and Seconds. Is there any easy way to do this using LINQ without manually summing the minutes and seconds?

Comment: I agree with @StephenChung. These Linq samples might also help you: <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336747#sumSimple>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose you mean TimeSpan instead of DateTime?  You can't add DateTime's...

To sum TimeSpan's:

1. list.Sum(span => span.TotalSeconds) ==> total seconds
2. TimeSpan.FromSeconds(...) ==> Convert total seconds back to time span

You can then use properties in TimeSpan to reformat it back to hours, minutes, seconds etc.

Comment: A one-liner method of doing this without having to go through `int`s is by using the `Aggregate` function, like so: `list.Aggregate((sum, next) => sum + next)`. The `TimeSpan` you get out of that method will be the sum of all the `TimeSpan`s in the list.

Comment: Bravo in making this one-liner.  +1

Answer (score 3):

+1 for Stephen's answers.

Just for fun... if you really do want "to get sum of Minutes and Seconds" then:

```
 class MyClass
 {
     public DateTime DateTimeMember {get;set;}
     // other stuff
 }


 var myObjects = new List<MyClass>();

 // fill list...

 // 3 possible things you might be interested in
 var myMinuteSum = myObjects.Sum(x => x.DateTimeMember.Minute);
 var mySecondSum = myObjects.Sum(x => x.DateTimeMember.Second);     
 var myOddTotalOfMinutesAndSecondsInSeconds = myObjects.Sum(x => x.DateTimeMember.Minute * 60 + x.DateTimeMember.Second);
```